# How can I easily access all post titles for editing from WooCommerce in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have imported a ton of products, but I need to go through and edit every title for conciseness. I went into the database in phpMyAdmin, but can't seem to locate the titles.

I looked under wp_posts > indexes, but can't quite figure it out.

I want to basically bring up all titles in a big list in phpmyadmin and go through editing them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WooCommerce but from a looking at their [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/), products are stored as `product` post type. This means you can run an SQL query in phpMyAdmin to only show posts matching that post type.

```sql
SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

The above query will return all posts matching the product post type but only return the `post_title` (a.k.a the product title).

[image: phpMyAdmin SQL example]

If you want to show all fields run the following.

```sql
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

**Back up your database before doing anything, just incase!**